# loading a .RData file into session but no object loaded in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I got my analysis results in R (an object called `obj`) and save it as an .RData file `obj-result.RData`. Now in Shiny, at the beginning of the `ui.R` file, I put `load("obj-results.RData")` so that each time Shiny is run, this object can be loaded into R session, i.e. I expect that the `obj` object would be available to use in subsequent steps, such as `obj@data`, `obj@sample`, etc.

However, I find that `load` won't make the `obj` object available in current R session, so that Shiny could not find the quantities required. Is there anything I missed in loading the .RData object? Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe the object path is incomplete/incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that, whenever an object is used in the `ui.R` and/or `server.R`, the relevant objects must be loaded in the same file. Otherwise, shiny won't know where to find the object from other files (even they're in the same directory and loaded).

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that! Wasn't clear from the documentation - at least I didn't find it in the otherwise excellent tutorials and articles on their site.

Answer (score 2):

I also load a `.RData` file in my deployed ShinyApp ; my app works from this file. I also had difficulties to understand how the loading worked.
In this example [here](http://blog.snap.uaf.edu/2013/05/20/r-sampling-app-version-2/) the statement `load(...)` is located in the `server.R`. This manner to proceed didn't work in my ShinyApp (the app was displayed but became immediately gray) - I don't know why. The solution was only to put the `load(...)` statement in a `global.R` file : `load("./data/obj-result.RData", envir=.GlobalEnv)`.