# Shiny: Dynamically load .RData file

Tags: r, shiny

I am using Shiny as an interface for viewing tables stored locally in a series of `.RData` files however I am unable to get the table to render.

My `server` code is like this:

```
output$table1 <- renderTable({
load(paste0(input$one,"/",input$two,".RData"))
myData})
```

On the `ui` side I am simply displaying the table in the main panel.

[This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654679/loading-a-rdata-file-into-session-but-no-object-loaded-in-shiny) suggests that the issue is that the environment that the data is loaded into goes away so the data isn't there to display. They suggest creating a `global` file and loading the `.RData` file in there, but I don't believe I will be able to load the data dynamically that way. Any guidance on how to use `.RData` files effectively within `shiny` would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you  just need to move the `load` statement outside of the `renderTable` function. So you should have

```
load(paste0(input$one,"/",input$two,".RData"))
output$table1 <- renderTable({myData})
```

If you look at the help file for `renderTable`, the first argument is

> expr:  An expression that returns an R object that can be used with
>   xtable.

`load` does not return this.

Comment: l think it's one step further, he has to `load` before `shinyServer()` is called. I could never get load() to load into the correct environment when I tried to load it either within a render function, or within observe.

Comment: Actually, I just tried it and everything is fine via `runAppDir` where `load` is called within `shinyServer`

Comment: I'm probably messing something: https://gist.github.com/csgillespie/dfed8e3a8796d603ae2d Looking at the `shinyServer` help page, it appears to have changed in recent versions of shiny.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. If you're using a reactive function, loading inside gets really messy because of scoping.

Comment: I used another approach using `fileInput`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894780/cant-read-an-rdata-fileinput-with-shiny?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: You cannot load like this outside a reactive context. This approach doesn't seem to work well in many applications.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by "tricking" R Shiny. I make a BOGUS textOutput, and in renderText, call a external function that, based in the input selected, sets the already globally loaded environments to a single environment called "e". Note, you MUST manually load all RDatas into environments in global.R first, with this approach. Assuming your data isn't that large, or  that you don't have a million RDatas, this seems like a reasonable hack.

By essentially creating a loadEnvFn() like the below that returns a string input passed as input$datasetNumber, you can avoid the scoping issues that occur when you put code in a reactive({}) context. I tried to do a TON of things, but they all required reactive contexts. This way, I could change the objects loaded in e, without having to wrap a reactive({}) scope around my shiny server code.

```
#Global Environment Pre-loaded before Shiny Server
e = new.env()
dataset1 = new.env()
load("dataset1.RData", env=dataset1)
dataset2 = new.env()
load("dataset2.RData", env=dataset2)
dataset3 = new.env()
load("dataset3.RData", env=dataset3)


ui = fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel(title="View Datasets"),

  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel
    sidebarPanel(width=3, radioButtons(inputId = "datasetNumber", label = "From which dataset do you want to display sample data?", choices = list("Dataset1", "Dataset2", "Dataset3"), selected = "Dataset2")
    ),

    # Main panel
    mainPanel(width = 9, 
      textOutput("dataset"), # Bogus textOutput
      textOutput("numInEnv")
    )
  )
)

loadEnvFn = function(input) {
  if (input$datasetNumber=="Dataset1") { 
    .GlobalEnv$e = dataset1
  } else if (input$datasetNumber=="Dataset2") { 
    .GlobalEnv$e = dataset2
  } else { 
    .GlobalEnv$e = dataset3
  }
  # Bogus return string unrelated to real purpose of function loadEnvFn
  return(input$datasetNumber) 
}

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$dataset = renderText(sprintf("Dataset chosen was %s", loadEnvFn(input)))         # Bogus output
  output$numInEnv = renderText(sprintf("# objects in environment 'e': %d", length(ls(e))))
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```